# Remove first part of url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am quite sure that this is the right way, but it's not working. I'm trying to rewrite this

domain.com/halloo/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg

to

domain.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg

using this in the .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/halloo/wp-content/(.*)$ /wp-content/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I can't figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex targets for rewrite rules in htaccess files won't start with a `/`, which means your rule will never match (because there's never a request that starts with `/`).

Also, your rule takes the request `/halloo/wp-content/foo` and **redirects the browser** to `/wp-content/foo`. If you want to rewrite it internally so that `/halloo/wp-content/foo` remains in the URL address bar, remove the `R=301,` part from the flags.

```
RewriteRule ^halloo/wp-content/(.*)$ /wp-content/$1 [L]
```

This means you must *request* `domain.com/halloo/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg` in the browser. If you actually wanted it the other way around, just swap the "from regex" and the "to URI":

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/(.*)$ /halloo/wp-content/$1 [L]
```

Edit:

To get rid of the `/halloo/` from the browser's address bar, you need something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+halloo/wp-content([^ \?]+)
RewriteRule ^ /wp-content$%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you. I mixed redirect and rewrite. Is there any way to change the url in the address bar to the new url as well?